# Problem injecting a dojox.datagrid into a dijit.layout.contentpane into a dijit.layout.tabcontainer

Tags: grid, dojo

didn't work in FF. Did I use the right function order of grid, tabStudios, tabContainer and startups? Neither the tabcontainer nor the grid have been injected. Has someone a suggestions for this problem?

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    var tabContainer=new dijit.layout.TabContainer({region:"center",id:"studio-tab"});
    var tabStudios=new dijit.layout.ContentPane({title:"Studioliste",id:"studios"});
    var readStore=new dojox.data.QueryReadStore({url:"index/studiolistdata",requestMethod:"post"});
    var grid=new dojox.grid.DataGrid({store:readStore,
                                      id:"studiolistgrid",
                                      rowsPerPage:30,
                                      delayScroll:true,
                                      structure:'.Zend_Json::encode($attr).',
                                      loadingMessage:"Loading..."
                                     });

   //problems start here

   grid.placeAt(tabStudios.containerNode);
   grid.startup();

   tabStudios.placeAt(tabContainer);
   tabStudios.startup();

   tabContainer.placeAt(dijit.byId("studio-content").containerNode);
   tabContainer.startup();

   //problems hopefully ended here
 });
```

```
<div id="studio-content" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="center">

    <ul>
      <li>XY</li>
      <li>XZ</li>
      <li>YY</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is a year and a bit ago and I don't know if it's related, but I found this thread ranking high in searches on google regarding datagrids not loading in contentPanes.

The issue here is that you were using **dijit.layout.ContentPane** which does not execute scripts; not even alert('test');.

You need to use **dojox.layout.ContentPane** which has executeScripts functionality (and is enabled by default).

There's really nothing more to say about the solution to this problem, but I blogged about it:
http://www.rvdavid.com.au/contentpane-in-dojo-not-loading-scripts-this-is-how-you-fix-it/

It irritated me so much that it took me so long to find such a simple solution.

So I'm posting an answer here, 1 year later, in case any more people run into this issue and find themselves on this SO question.

I hope someone finds it useful.

Cheers.

Comment: Well, it might help if I could read your blog which is on a domain that has expired. . . :)

Comment: Sorry man - updated the link to new domain. I lost interest in the blog for a little while and actually let it expire. I recently got a new domain and thought ah well, guess I can put it up.

http://www.rvdavid.com.au/contentpane-in-dojo-not-loading-scripts-this-is-how-you-fix-it/

Note though, that it's like over 5 years old. :) Hope it's still current.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I find was to change the ContentPane into a BorderContainer and placeAt my TabContainer within the DataGrid into it. This works fine for me in Firefox and IE7.

changes:

```
- tabContainer.placeAt(dijit.byId("studio-content").containerNode);
+ tabContainer.placeAt(dijit.byId("studio-content"),"only");

....

-<div id="studio-content" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="center">
-  <ul>
-    <li>XY</li>
-    <li>XZ</li>
-    <li>YY</li>
-  </ul>
-</div>

+<div id="studio-content" dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" region="center">
+  <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="center">
+    <ul>
+      <li>XY</li>
+      <li>XZ</li>
+      <li>YY</li>
+    </ul>
+  </div>
+</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue, 
        like not able to see/load grid inside the tabcontainer/contentpane. After going through, what observed is grid will be loaded before content pane is loaded, so

1. try loading grid after content pane is laoded.
2. or provide some default width and height to content pane.

Used Option 2 and it worked. Used as below:

```
var conPane= new ContentPane({"style":width:90%;"});
```